# How does TRIM work in macOS High Sierra?

Tags: high-sierra, ssd, encryption, data-recovery, trim

Since all MacBooks with Apple-SSDs have TRIM enabled, I was wondering if trimming would “reset/prepare” the blocks for new writes, or would they leave the blocks there until a new write comes in.

If blocks are reset/prepared in advance of new writes, would forensic recoverability of data still be possible?

Answer (score 1):

MacOS issues the TRIM command to the disk drive controller. From that point on the operating system have no control over the process. What happens is entirely drive dependent.

The most common is that the blocks are marked as unused in a bitmap in the drive, but the contents are otherwise left alone. In order to prevent the possibility of forensics, you’ll need to send a secure erase command instead.

Depending on the drive, that will typically either erase the blocks or throw away an encryption key - or possibly both (typically on Intel drives). The end result is making it impossible to retrieve the data that was previously stored in those blocks.

Comment: In the second paragraph, you state that it is most common that the contents are left alone. However, in the third paragraph, you say that typically in intel drives, blocks are erased or the (file) encryption key is thrown.

Comment: MacBooks are intel based (i5/i7 core) with an Apple SSD controller and Samsung-manufactured SSD. Does the third paragraph apply?

Comment: Also, by erased, do you mean that the SSD specifically erases that block containing the file (bypassing wear levelling)? If the encryption key is thrown (deleted), is it possible to match the key to the file it decrypts?

Comment: I’m with the answer here. There’s no evidence I’ve seen that macOS has any jurisdiction or care what the storage does with low level data once a trim command is issued. There’s no reason each specific vendor and possibly each specific firmware for a given device might not implement this differently.

Comment: @NoMoreErrors Regarding your first comment: You need to read my answer again. The second paragraph about blocks being left alone are when the trim command is used. The third paragraph concerns the scenario where you use the secure erase commands.

Comment: @NoMoreErrors Regarding your second comment: The main CPU has nothing to say in this regard - it doesn't matter if its Intel, AMD or something else. The only thing that matters is the firmware on the SSD.

Comment: @NoMoreErrors Regarding your third comment: No, the encryption keys are not used on the file level at all - there's no possibility of "matching" keys to specific files.

Comment: @jksoegaard appreciate your follow up. The secure erase command you refer to wouldn’t be “diskutil secureerase freespace /dev/disk0/“, would it? Apple says that secureerase doesn’t securely remove all data and removed it from High Sierra. I read that the reason behind it because SE does overwrites on the data which will not work because of wear levelling within the SSD.

Comment: I was trying to retrieve the unused blocks using commercial forensic tools after emptying trash (first time I used an imager to produce a bitstream copy, second time I used the live SSD on target disk mode); I couldn’t. Are there practical limitations that prevent recovery? Is it true that I should’ve gone to access the SSD directly (chip disassembly or connect the logic board containing the the SSD through SATA/PCIE/NVME) instead of querying for through the MacOS interface?

Comment: Bitstream image of all blocks including unused and unallocated should produce positive results..

Comment: @NoMoreErrors No, I’m not referring to that secure erase functionality in Disk Utility. I’m referring to commands on the same protocol level as the TRIM command.

Comment: @NoMoreErrors If you have deleted files and their blocks have been TRIMmed away, you’re obviously not going to be able to read their contents in an image taken from the usual disk interface. For that you’ll need to read the SSD blocks directly bypassing the disk firmware. If you’re asking these types of questions, that will usually be out of your reach. Contact a pro!